# segmentation fault when converting numbers from a base to another base

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a program in C that converts numbers from any base to any base. It worked from decimal to any base but when I implemented the conversion from any base I get segmentation fault: I have to specify that I don't use an IDE, just gcc command linking my program to a static library. The strange thing is that I tried to compile on Windows and it worked. Can somebody help me out?

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> //library for isdigit
#include <string.h>
#include "ylantron.h" //<-- my library

#define MAX_SYMBOLS 36

void pause();
char* convert(char* value, int startingBase, int endingBase);
char* swapArray(char *oldArray);

// MAIN

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

/* CHECK ARGUMENTS NUMBER */
if (argc != 4 ){
  printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m Invalid number argument\n");
  pause();
  return 1;
}

/* CHECK ARGUMENTS */
if (   (isdigit(argv[1][0])==0)   ||   (isdigit(argv[2][0])==0)   ||   (isdigit(argv[3][0])==0)   ){
  printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m One of the arguments is not a number\n");
  pause();
  return 1;
}

/* CHECKING BASES */
int check=0;
char *baseType=(char*)calloc(9,sizeof(char));
char *infSup=(char*)calloc(10,sizeof(char));
int numMinMax;

if (atoi(argv[1])<2)   { strcpy(baseType,"starting");   strcpy(infSup,"inferior");   numMinMax=2;   check=1; }
else if (atoi(argv[1])>MAX_SYMBOLS)   { strcpy(baseType,"starting");   strcpy(infSup,"superior");   numMinMax=MAX_SYMBOLS;   check=1; }
else if (atoi(argv[3])<2)   { strcpy(baseType,"ending");   strcpy(infSup,"inferior");   numMinMax=2;   check=1; }
else if (atoi(argv[3])>MAX_SYMBOLS)   { strcpy(baseType,"ending");   strcpy(infSup,"superior");   numMinMax=MAX_SYMBOLS;   check=1; }

if (check==1){
  printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m The %s base can't be %s to %d\n",   baseType,   infSup,   numMinMax);

  free(baseType);
  free(infSup);

  pause();
  return 1; }

int base_from, base_to;
char* val;

base_from=atoi(argv[1]);
val=argv[2];
base_to=atoi(argv[3]);

if (base_from==base_to)   { printf("\n\e[93m[?]\e[39m Why you want me to convert a number with equal bases?"); pause(); return 1; }

printf("\nThe result is %s\n\n",converti(val,base_from,base_to));

return 0;
}

// FUNCTIONS

void pause() {

printf("\nPress any key...");
getch();
printf("\n");

}


char* convert(char* value, int startingBase, int endingBase){

char symbols[]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
char *valueArray=NULL;
int val=0;


if (startingBase != 10 ){
  for (int i=0;i<(strlen(value)/sizeof(char));i++){
     for (int j=0;j<MAX_SYMBOLS;j++){
        if (value[i]==symbols[j]){
           val+=j;
           break;
        }
     }
  }
}

printf("val: %d",val);

for (int i=1;val!=0;){
  valueArray=(char *)realloc(valueArray,(++i)*sizeof(char));
  valueArray[i-2]=symbols[(val%endingBase)];
  valueArray[i-1]='\0';
  val/=endingBase;
}

swapArray(valueArray);

return valueArray;

}

char* swapArray(char *oldArray){

char old;
int i,j;

for (i=0,j=strlen(oldArray)-1;i<(strlen(oldArray)/2);i++,j--){
  old=oldArray[i];
  oldArray[i]=oldArray[j];
  oldArray[j]=old;
}

return oldArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You had a few real bugs. Some would produce the crash. Others would produce incorrect results. First, I'll explain the bugs.

Further, below, I've produced two versions of your program. One that is annotated with comments showing the bugs [with fixes]. And, a second cleaned up version.

---

For the crash, working backwards:

1. `swapArray` was segfaulting because it was given a `NULL` pointer
2. `convert` would do `swapArray(valueArray)` and `valueArray` could/would be `NULL`
3. In `convert`, `valueArray` would be `NULL` if `val` was zero (i.e.) the loop with the `realloc` would have zero iterations
4. `val` could/would be zero if `startingBase` was 10 (i.e.) the first two loops would not be executed
5. These two loops should *always* be executed (i.e.) The `if (startingBase != 10)` test was superfluous/wrong
6. Also, even with fixing #5, `val` could still be zero [legitimately] (i.e.) the original value *is* zero. So, the `realloc` loop has to be rearchitected to execute at least *once*, to *guarantee* that `valueArray` is *not* `NULL`.

---

Okay, that handles the crash, but the program would still produce incorrect results because above the line:

```
val += j;
```

we need to multiply by the starting base as in:

```
val *= startingBase;
val += j;
```

---

Here is the annotated version.

The style is: `#if 0 /*original code*/ #else /*fixed code*/ #endif` and there are comments explaining things [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>                      // library for isdigit
#include <string.h>
#include <curses.h>
//#include "ylantron.h"                 // <-- my library

#define MAX_SYMBOLS 36

void pause();
char *convert(char *value, int startingBase, int endingBase);
char *swapArray(char *oldArray);

// MAIN

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* CHECK ARGUMENTS NUMBER */
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m Invalid number argument\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    /* CHECK ARGUMENTS */
    if ((isdigit(argv[1][0]) == 0) || (isdigit(argv[2][0]) == 0) || (isdigit(argv[3][0]) == 0)) {
        printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m One of the arguments is not a number\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    /* CHECKING BASES */
    int check = 0;
    char *baseType = (char *) calloc(9, sizeof(char));
    char *infSup = (char *) calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    int numMinMax;

    int base_from;
    int base_to;
    char *val;

    base_from = atoi(argv[1]);
    val = argv[2];
    base_to = atoi(argv[3]);

    if (base_from < 2) {
        strcpy(baseType, "starting");
        strcpy(infSup, "inferior");
        numMinMax = 2;
        check = 1;
    }
    else if (base_from > MAX_SYMBOLS) {
        strcpy(baseType, "starting");
        strcpy(infSup, "superior");
        numMinMax = MAX_SYMBOLS;
        check = 1;
    }
    else if (base_to < 2) {
        strcpy(baseType, "ending");
        strcpy(infSup, "inferior");
        numMinMax = 2;
        check = 1;
    }
    else if (base_to > MAX_SYMBOLS) {
        strcpy(baseType, "ending");
        strcpy(infSup, "superior");
        numMinMax = MAX_SYMBOLS;
        check = 1;
    }

    if (check == 1) {
        printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m The %s base can't be %s to %d\n",
            baseType, infSup, numMinMax);

        free(baseType);
        free(infSup);

        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    if (base_from == base_to) {
        printf("\n\e[93m[?]\e[39m Why you want me to convert a number with equal bases?");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nThe result is %s\n\n", convert(val, base_from, base_to));

    return 0;
}

// FUNCTIONS

void
pause()
{

    printf("\nPress any key...");
    getch();
    printf("\n");
}

char *
convert(char *value, int startingBase, int endingBase)
{

    char symbols[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
    char *valueArray = NULL;
    int val = 0;

    // NOTE/BUG: this should _always_ be executed regardless of base
#if 0
    if (startingBase != 10) {
#endif
        for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(value) / sizeof(char)); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SYMBOLS; j++) {
                if (value[i] == symbols[j]) {
                    // NOTE/BUG: when assembling the number we must multiply by
                    // the base
#if 1
                    val *= startingBase;
#endif
                    val += j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
#if 0
    }
#endif

    // NOTE: for debug?
    printf("val: %d", val);

    // NOTE/BUGS:
    // (1) if val is zero, this loop will never be executed and
    //     valueArray will remain NULL
    // (2) if startingBase _is_ 10, then val could _never_ be non-zero
#if 0
    for (int i = 1; val != 0;) {
        valueArray = (char *) realloc(valueArray, (++i) * sizeof(char));
        valueArray[i - 2] = symbols[(val % endingBase)];
        valueArray[i - 1] = '\0';
        val /= endingBase;
    }
#else
    int i = 1;
    while (1) {
        valueArray = (char *) realloc(valueArray, (++i) * sizeof(char));
        valueArray[i - 2] = symbols[(val % endingBase)];
        valueArray[i - 1] = '\0';
        val /= endingBase;
        if (val == 0)
            break;
    }
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG: this produces a segfault if valueArray is NULL
    swapArray(valueArray);

    return valueArray;
}

char *
swapArray(char *oldArray)
{

    char old;
    int i;
    int j;

    // NOTE/BUG: strlen gives segfault if oldArray is NULL
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(oldArray) - 1; i < (strlen(oldArray) / 2); i++, j--) {
        old = oldArray[i];
        oldArray[i] = oldArray[j];
        oldArray[j] = old;
    }

    return oldArray;
}
```

---

Here is the cleaned up version.

Aside from removing the "ugliness" of the the old code and the "NOTE/BUG" comments, mostly, it's changing the loops that deal with string from calling `strlen` repeatedly inside the loop to looking for the EOS character instead. I've changed this in a few loops and produced a few variants of `swapArray` to show what could be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>                      // library for isdigit
#include <string.h>
#include <curses.h>
//#include "ylantron.h"                 // <-- my library

#define MAX_SYMBOLS 36

void pause();
char *convert(char *value, int startingBase, int endingBase);
char *swapArray(char *oldArray);

// MAIN

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* CHECK ARGUMENTS NUMBER */
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m Invalid number argument\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    /* CHECK ARGUMENTS */
    if ((isdigit(argv[1][0]) == 0) || (isdigit(argv[2][0]) == 0) || (isdigit(argv[3][0]) == 0)) {
        printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m One of the arguments is not a number\n");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    /* CHECKING BASES */
    int check = 0;
    char *baseType = (char *) calloc(9, sizeof(char));
    char *infSup = (char *) calloc(10, sizeof(char));
    int numMinMax;

    int base_from;
    int base_to;
    char *val;

    base_from = atoi(argv[1]);
    val = argv[2];
    base_to = atoi(argv[3]);

    if (base_from < 2) {
        strcpy(baseType, "starting");
        strcpy(infSup, "inferior");
        numMinMax = 2;
        check = 1;
    }
    else if (base_from > MAX_SYMBOLS) {
        strcpy(baseType, "starting");
        strcpy(infSup, "superior");
        numMinMax = MAX_SYMBOLS;
        check = 1;
    }
    else if (base_to < 2) {
        strcpy(baseType, "ending");
        strcpy(infSup, "inferior");
        numMinMax = 2;
        check = 1;
    }
    else if (base_to > MAX_SYMBOLS) {
        strcpy(baseType, "ending");
        strcpy(infSup, "superior");
        numMinMax = MAX_SYMBOLS;
        check = 1;
    }

    if (check == 1) {
        printf("\n\e[91m[X]\e[39m The %s base can't be %s to %d\n",
            baseType, infSup, numMinMax);

        free(baseType);
        free(infSup);

        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    if (base_from == base_to) {
        printf("\n\e[93m[?]\e[39m Why you want me to convert a number with equal bases?");
        pause();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nThe result is %s\n\n", convert(val, base_from, base_to));

    return 0;
}

// FUNCTIONS

void
pause()
{

    printf("\nPress any key...");
    getch();
    printf("\n");
}

char *
convert(char *value, int startingBase, int endingBase)
{
    char symbols[] = { "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" };
    char *valueArray = NULL;
    int val = 0;

    for (int chr = *value++;  chr != 0;  chr = *value++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_SYMBOLS; j++) {
            if (chr == symbols[j]) {
                val *= startingBase;
                val += j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int i = 1;
    while (1) {
        valueArray = (char *) realloc(valueArray, (++i) * sizeof(char));
        valueArray[i - 2] = symbols[(val % endingBase)];
        valueArray[i - 1] = '\0';
        val /= endingBase;
        if (val == 0)
            break;
    }

    swapArray(valueArray);

    return valueArray;
}

char *
swapArray(char *oldArray)
{
    char old;
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(oldArray) - 1; i < (strlen(oldArray) / 2); i++, j--) {
        old = oldArray[i];
        oldArray[i] = oldArray[j];
        oldArray[j] = old;
    }

    return oldArray;
}

char *
swapArray_2(char *oldArray)
{
    char old;
    int len;
    int i;
    int j;

    len = strlen(oldArray);
    for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i < (len / 2); i++, j--) {
        old = oldArray[i];
        oldArray[i] = oldArray[j];
        oldArray[j] = old;
    }

    return oldArray;
}

char *
swapArray_3(char *oldArray)
{
    char *lhs;
    char *rhs;
    char old;

    lhs = oldArray;
    rhs = &lhs[strlen(lhs) - 1];

    for (;  lhs < rhs;  ++lhs, --rhs) {
        old = *lhs;
        *lhs = *rhs;
        *rhs = old;
    }

    return oldArray;
}
```